# Use ESP8266 to power (HF165FD) relay

Tags: relay, esp8266, llc-converter

I am working on a project where I need to remotely switch the power for my dryer.
I am using a [ESP8266](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KW54YSK) which outputs 3.3V to the [LLC](https://make.net.za/product/4-channel-bi-directional-logic-level-converter/) which switches the [5V relay](https://www.macrogroup.ru/sites/default/files/uploads/catalog/Relay/Power_relay/hf165fd_en.pdf) to the dryer.

I am having problems powering the relay. If I connect the 5V wire from the ESP8266 to the relay directly the relay works (audible click), but when I add in the LLC it does not work.

The LLC should be taking the 3.3V signal D1 and outputting a 5V signal that can power the relay, but that is not happening.

I checked that a signal is coming from D1 as that powers a LED.
The wire from H1 also powers a LED so the LLC is connected.

I'm more of a software guy and this is my first hardware project. Any suggestions appreciated.

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Could you please ask a specific question?

Comment: Your 5 volts is shorted to GND. Use a BJT instead of the LLC is my best advice because there's nothing in the data for the LLC that says it can deliver several dozen mA to power the 5 volt relay i.e. do what EEs normally do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you are taking the incorrect approach with the level converter. It is designed for logic, nothing more. Use a 1 Channel Relay Module With Optocoupler Isolation, there are many varieties available. They can be purchased for under $6 US and some even Support High and/or Low Level Trigger. Use that relay to switch your power relay. Microprocessors and logic devices in general tend to fry if you switch inductive loads such as relays.

Comment: I did not realize that LLC's are only for logic. I'll do what you suggest. Thank you.